# Python can not find file which is searched by imported module

Tags: python, spyder

To be specific: My script uses another self-written script, call it sub_script which is placed in an subfolder. Furthermore, in the subfolder is an file which is uses a datasheet, placed in the subfolder, too.

```py
#main_script

from subfolder import sub_script

sub_script.function()


#sub_scribt
import pandas as pd

def import():

   data=pd.ExcelFile(Filename.xlsx)
   print(data)
```

## Error

[Errno 2] No such file or directory

So I guess this happens is because Python searches in the main-folder section and not in the sub-folder section. But how can I tell Python to exactly do that?

(It would be great if Python does this automatically, that means that it searches the data always in the sub-folder section, independently from the name of the sub-folder).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `from subfolder import sub_scribt` but you're calling `sub_script.function()` !

Comment: your error description is rather cryptic. Which line exactly throws the error? And in general, I'd not call a function `def import()` since this would redefine python's `import`

Comment: @agupta: this also works, after `from subfolder import sub_script` you can call `sub_script.function()` - it's just not that pretty I'd say. Only a matter of taste.

Comment: Which python version are you using? The import semantics changed a lot between 2.* and 3.*.

Comment: It's Python 3.7.3 .

Comment: why not specify the path to your data explicitly in the call `data=pd.ExcelFile(Filename.xlsx)`? Just pass it to the function... would make your code more versatile anyway.

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm pointing out the typo error that he made, scribt in place of script.

Comment: @agupta haha ok didn't notice that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Python only searches the current directory i.e. the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and `sys.path`.

try this:

```
#main_script

import sys 
sys.path.insert(1, "/path/to/subfolder") # 0 is the script itself
import sub_script
```